# Get values from multiple selections with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var data = document.querySelectorAll('span.data-01', 'span.data-02');
    for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
        console.log(data[i].className + " " + data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) 
        //var one = parseInt(data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        //var two = parseInt(data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);  
    }  
    //total = one + two;
    //console.log(total); 
};
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="info">
<span class="data-01">9000</span>
<span class="data-02">6500</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**How do you put each of these values into a variable to be outputted in the console log?**

I want to be able to add values marked by class data-01 + data-02 (15500). For some reason only data-01 is shown in the console.

**Answer**
querySelectorAll () requires

this

```
'span.data-01', 'span.data-02'
```

should be this

```
'span.data-01, span.data-02'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop through the result and get the nodeValue of the text node:

```
var data = document.querySelectorAll('span.data-01,span.data-02');
var sum=0;
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    console.log(data[i].className + " " + data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    sum=sum + parseFloat(data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

Or:

```
var data = document.querySelector('div.info').childNodes;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].nodeType == 1) {
        console.log(data[i].className + " " + data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        sum = sum + parseFloat(data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how would I assign variables data-01 and data-02 to this loop?

Comment: console.log(data[i].className +" " + data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

Comment: Is there a way to view everything querySelectorAll selects?

Comment: I believe console.log(document.querySelectorAll('span.data-01,span.data-02')) should do it.

Comment: This was the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var data = document.querySelectorAll('span.data-01, span.data-02');
```

Comment: How would you add the found values together?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Perhaps you should edit the question to show what you want to show up in the console.

Comment: I've updated my question. Do I need to use multiple selections for different elements?