# document.querySelectorAll() of multiple values

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

I have this code:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('something1')">Click</a>
<a href="javascript:prompt('something2')">Click</a>
<a href="javascript:alert('something3')">Click</a>
<a href="javascript:prompt('something4')">Click</a>
```

To get individual set element, I use `document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='javascript:alert(");` and `document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='javascript:prompt");`.

Now, how can use a generic `document.querySelectorAll()` to get all such `<a href` elements which contains alert, and prompt?

I tried this:

`document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='javascript:prompt(,a[href^='javascript:alert(");`

`document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='javascript:prompt(","a[href^='javascript:alert(");`

and so many. But it doesn't work, got `"DOMException - not a valid selector"` error.

Any help?

Comment: Just select them individually as before and merge the results?

Comment: Yes, that would work. But, can I make it in one statement? I hope [there's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18938563/5132413) a way

Comment: Yeah it's possible, give me a sec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector is not valid

1. Missing closing quote of attribute value(`'`).
2. Missing ending of attribute selector `]`.
3. Also use **[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** to get NodeList, **[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** only return single element .

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='javascript:prompt('],a[href^='javascript:alert(']")
  //----------------------------------------------------^^---------------------------^^^
);
```

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('something1')">Click</a>
<a href="javascript:prompt('something2')">Click</a>
<a href="javascript:alert('something3')">Click</a>
<a href="javascript:prompt('something4')">Click</a>
```

Comment: Please correct the code snippet it is not working now: **"SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'",**

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks.